# Swift // Make a phone call and choose the line (Dual SIM/ eSIM iPhone)

Tags: swift, iphone, phone-call

how to choose the line from an iPhone to initialize the phone call (SIM or eSIM)

I am using UIApplication.shared.open(...) with "tel://1234567890" to make a phone call.
This will choose the standard default line from mobile settings. Is it possible to include the line (SIM/ eSIM) in the link and if how?

thx 
Jo

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible when using the `tel` scheme. My hope is that Apple some day will add the option to let the user choose which SIM card to use, in the dialog that opens ("Call *number*" or "Cancel")